# How update exiftool in 13.10 lubuntu

Tags: 13.10, updates, lubuntu

I have lubuntu 13.10 and exiftool 9.13.
How can i update exiftool to version 9.55?
I downloaded the newest exiftool from www and do everything to install it according to:
http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html#Unix
everything went fine, but synaptic still says that i have 9.13 and of course it still work like the older one app, it didnt update! In repository the newest ver is 9.13 what is not true.
Simply i am not linux guru, just user and want to have exiftool with KML support to geotag my poics and new ver of exiftool do that but i dont know how to update my lubuntu to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `Changes` file included in the [source tarball](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/Image-ExifTool-9.56.tar.gz), the KML feature that you need is available since `exiftool` 9.41:

> Nov. 16, 2013 - Version 9.41
>
> - Added the ability to use multiple group qualifiers on tag names when writing
>     and copying (ie. "-QuickTime:Time:All=now")
> - **Added ability to geotag from Google Location Services KML files**
> - Added a new Pentax LensType (thanks Louis Granboulan)
> - Added a new Canon LensType (thanks David Monro)
> - Added a new Sony LensType2 (thanks Jos Roost)
> - Decode a bunch more Nikon, Canon, Sony and FujiFilm WhiteBalance tags
>     (thanks LibRaw)
> - Extract information from the new Pentax APP7 segment

Unless you absolutely need a feature only present in a version > 9.41, your best option is to download the debian package of the 14.04 (Trusty) archive (just select the right mirror for your location):

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/libimage-exiftool-perl/download

Then open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and go to the folder where you've just downloaded `libimage-exiftool-perl_9.46-1_all.deb` and type:

```
sudo dpkg -i libimage-exiftool-perl_9.46-1_all.deb
```

**Note**: It's possible to install this package on Ubuntu 13.10 because the only dependency is on `perl` (which is obviously installed with Ubuntu 13.10)

Comment: Cool, could you please up-vote (^) my answer? Thanks